# Creating classType from string to pass as concrete type to generic parameter Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have `protocol P`, `class A and B` and my aim is to call generic method `a<T: P>(_: T.Type)` with class type parameter created from strings.

```
protocol P: class {
    static var p: String { get }
}

extension P {
    static var p: String { return String(describing: self) }
}

class A: P {

    func a<T: P>(_: T.Type) {
        print(T.p)
    }
}

class B: P {}
```

Below code works because forcefully casting to B.Type fixes the class type

```
let b = "B"
let type = NSClassFromString(b) as! B.Type
A().a(type)
```

But if lets say we have an array of class names without knowing their concrete types, how can we pass those?

```
["ClassA", "ClassB", "ClassC"].forEach({ className in
   let type = NSClassFromString(className) as! ????
   A().a(type)
})
```

Comment: Have you explored Swift `KeyPath` ? Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath

Comment: @user1046037 To define a KeyPath, wouldn't we require Root type? same thing we need to know here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, type parameters in generic declarations needs to be solved at compile-time.

So, your `????` needs to be a concrete type conforming to `P`. But you cannot use any of the concrete types `A.Type` or `B.Type` as you describe.

And you may know you cannot use `P.Type`, as protocol `P` does not conform to `P` itself in Swift.

---

How about declaring the method `a(_:)` as non-generic?

```
class A: P {

    func a(_ type: P.Type) {
        print(type.p)
    }

}

["ModuleName.A", "ModuleName.B"].forEach({ className in
    let type = NSClassFromString(className) as! P.Type
        A().a(type)
})
```

You can pass class objects of type `P.Type` to the argument of type `P.Type`.